# The Secrets of Psalm 46

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

It's well-known that Shakespeare hid his name in the KJV translation of Psalm 46, but did you know that there's more to it?
A line-by-line analysis might uncover the cryptic excerpts he left behind.
[image]
What do some cryptic crosswords and Shakespeare have in common?

Transcription:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Street sign (2 wds) | 2 words |
| Distant | 6 words |
| German wine region | 3 words |
| Danube tributary | 3 words |
| Casing | 2 words |
| Center | 2 words |
| Among Us adjective | 3 words |
| Rage | 2 words |
| Follows a certain recipe direction | 4 words |
| Giggle | 3 words |
| Go bad | 2 words |

Comment: This is an impressive puzzle.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What do some cryptic crosswords and Shakespeare have in common?

> **THEY'RE BARRED**! (A 'barred crossword' is one which uses bars - boundary lines - between answers, rather than black squares; and Shakespeare is regularly referred to as 'The Bard of Avon'...)

How do we find this? First interpret the puzzle instructions to realise that we should be...

> ...looking for snippets within the verses of Psalm 46 (KJV) that could be the wordplay for **cryptic clues**. The column listing numbers of words tells us how many words within each verse make up this cryptic wordplay (e.g. the second entry tells us we need to find a 6-word snippet that leads to a word meaning 'Distant'). Note also that there are 11 entries in our list and 11 verses in Psalm 46 - we are likely looking for one answer per verse (and hopefully in order - thankfully, this turns out to be the case...).

This means our crossword clues can be interpreted as follows:

> (Verse number: Clue {number of words from verse} = *excerpt from Psalm 46* = Wordplay = **ANSWER**)
>
>  Verse 1: Street sign (2 wds) {2} = *...a very...* = ONE (a) + WAY (very) = **ONE WAY**
>  Verse 2: Distant {6} = *...fear, though the earth be removed...* = F(-e)AR = **FAR**
>  Verse 3: German wine region {3} = *...and be troubled...* = ANDBE* = **[BADEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baden_(wine_region))**
>  Verse 4: Danube tributary {3} = *...is a river...* = IS + A + R (river) = **ISAR**
>  Verse 5: Casing {2} = *...she shall...* = SHE'LL = **SHELL**
>  Verse 6: Center {2} = *...earth melted...* = EARTH* = **HEART**
>  Verse 7: Among Us adjective {3} = *...is with us...* = 'S + US = **SUS**
>  Verse 8: Rage {2} = *...behold the...* = SEE + THE = **SEETHE**
>  Verse 9: Follows a certain recipe direction {4} = *...the spear in sunder...* = THESPEAR* = **PREHEATS**
>  Verse 10: Giggle {3} = *...among the heathen...* = (-t)HE HE(-athen) = **HEHE**
>  Verse 11: Go bad {2} = *...is our...* = 'S + OUR = **SOUR**

These words can be placed in the crossword as follows:

> [image: Completed grid]

And the final answer can be extracted by...

> ...reading off the yellow letters in the order they are numbered in the diagram. This spells out: **THEY'RE BARRED**!

Comment: For reference, here's a link to [the text of the Psalm in question](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%2046&version=KJV).

Comment: Amazing puzzle and an amazing answer! I got the link between 11 clues and 11 lines but thats how far my brain could go :)